# JQuery show() method doesnot working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div block

```
        <div class="score-description col-sm-3">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                   <th> Score
                   </th>
                   <th> Description
                   </th>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>Poor</td>
                       ...
                       ...
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
```

I wanted to show this block when the following button is clicked.

```
<Button class="btn btn-warning show-score-description-button">
     Score Descriptions
</Button>
```

I have the following script to show the block

```
$(".show-score-description-button").click(function(){
       $(".score-description").show();
})
```

css for .score-description class is

```
.score-description{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: scroll;
        margin-top:-100px;
        height: 50%;
        margin-left: 7%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display: none;

    }
    .score-description table th{
        border: 2px solid #aaaabb;
    }
    .score-description table td{
        border: 2px solid #aaaabb;
    }
```

Problem is when i click the button the block is shown and immediately hides. What am I missing??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your button `type="button"`. Currently your `button` is submitting the page. So its shows the page in default state.

```
<Button type="button" class="btn btn-warning show-score-description-button">
 Score Descriptions
```

Comment: The OP's code works fine as it is, so this is the only logical answer here, +1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes code is fine only button is creating the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try `toggle()`

```
$(".show-score-description-button").click(function() {
    $(".score-description").toggle();
})
```